# Upgrading from Phaser v2.0.1 to v2.7.7 breaks sound

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I have just replaced the minified Phaser js with the latest version (2.7.7) in my phaser app and my audio in my app has stopped working. The rest of the app still works well. The code to load the audio is pretty simple - I first load the audio and then add the audio assigning it to an array.

```
game.load.audio('sound.correct', 'assets/sound.general/sound.correct.mp3');

general_sounds[0] = game.add.audio('sound.correct');
```

When I come to playing the audio I just use:

```
general_sounds[0].play()
```

Which worked in 2.0.1 but now I get the error I get is as per below:

```
phaser.min.js:3 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createBufferSource' of null
    at c.Sound.play (phaser.min.js:3)
    at <anonymous>:1:19
play    @   phaser.min.js:3
(anonymous) @   VM1834:1
```

What's more odd is that when I run the above 3 commands in the console the sound everything works fine.

Does anyone know what is going on?

EDIT: below is a simplified version of the code that I am using - with the below, `general_sounds[1]` plays but 0 and 2 don't. If I put the `loadGeneralSound();` call in `create(){}` instead of `preload(){}` I get the error below the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"> 
<head> 
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Snap - it's kids play!</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/phaser.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            margin: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

var game = new Phaser.Game(800, 600, Phaser.AUTO, '', { preload: preload, create: create});
var general_sounds = [];

function preload() {
    // load general sounds
    loadGeneralSound(); 
}

function create() {
    general_sounds[0].play();
    general_sounds[1].play();
    general_sounds[2].play();

}

// loads general sounds that are not object specific
function loadGeneralSound() {
    game.load.audio('sound.correct', 'assets/sound.general/sound.correct.mp3');
    game.load.audio('sound.incorrect', 'assets/sound.general/sound.incorrect.mp3');
    game.load.audio('voice.correct', 'assets/sound.general/sound.well_done.m4a');

    general_sounds[0] = game.add.audio('sound.correct');
    general_sounds[1] = game.add.audio('sound.incorrect');
    general_sounds[2] = game.add.audio('voice.correct');

}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Errors if I put the `loadGeneralSound();` call in `create(){}` instead of `preload(){}`:

```
   Phaser CE v2.7.7 | Pixi.js | WebGL | WebAudio     http://phaser.io ♥♥♥
phaser.min.js:3 Phaser.Cache.isSoundDecoded: Key "sound.correct" not found in Cache.
getItem @ phaser.min.js:3
isSoundDecoded @ phaser.min.js:3
play @ phaser.min.js:3
create @ snap.html:27
loadComplete @ phaser.min.js:3
preUpdate @ phaser.min.js:3
updateLogic @ phaser.min.js:3
update @ phaser.min.js:3
updateRAF @ phaser.min.js:3
window.requestAnimationFrame.forceSetTimeOut._onLoop @ phaser.min.js:3
phaser.min.js:3 Phaser.Cache.getSound: Key "sound.correct" not found in Cache.
getItem @ phaser.min.js:3
getSound @ phaser.min.js:3
play @ phaser.min.js:3
create @ snap.html:27
loadComplete @ phaser.min.js:3
preUpdate @ phaser.min.js:3
updateLogic @ phaser.min.js:3
update @ phaser.min.js:3
updateRAF @ phaser.min.js:3
window.requestAnimationFrame.forceSetTimeOut._onLoop @ phaser.min.js:3
phaser.min.js:3 Phaser.Cache.isSoundDecoded: Key "sound.incorrect" not found in Cache.
getItem @ phaser.min.js:3
isSoundDecoded @ phaser.min.js:3
play @ phaser.min.js:3
create @ snap.html:28
loadComplete @ phaser.min.js:3
preUpdate @ phaser.min.js:3
updateLogic @ phaser.min.js:3
update @ phaser.min.js:3
updateRAF @ phaser.min.js:3
window.requestAnimationFrame.forceSetTimeOut._onLoop @ phaser.min.js:3
phaser.min.js:3 Phaser.Cache.getSound: Key "sound.incorrect" not found in Cache.
getItem @ phaser.min.js:3
getSound @ phaser.min.js:3
play @ phaser.min.js:3
create @ snap.html:28
loadComplete @ phaser.min.js:3
preUpdate @ phaser.min.js:3
updateLogic @ phaser.min.js:3
update @ phaser.min.js:3
updateRAF @ phaser.min.js:3
window.requestAnimationFrame.forceSetTimeOut._onLoop @ phaser.min.js:3
phaser.min.js:3 Phaser.Cache.isSoundDecoded: Key "voice.correct" not found in Cache.
getItem @ phaser.min.js:3
isSoundDecoded @ phaser.min.js:3
play @ phaser.min.js:3
create @ snap.html:29
loadComplete @ phaser.min.js:3
preUpdate @ phaser.min.js:3
updateLogic @ phaser.min.js:3
update @ phaser.min.js:3
updateRAF @ phaser.min.js:3
window.requestAnimationFrame.forceSetTimeOut._onLoop @ phaser.min.js:3
phaser.min.js:3 Phaser.Cache.getSound: Key "voice.correct" not found in Cache.
getItem @ phaser.min.js:3
getSound @ phaser.min.js:3
play @ phaser.min.js:3
create @ snap.html:29
loadComplete @ phaser.min.js:3
preUpdate @ phaser.min.js:3
updateLogic @ phaser.min.js:3
update @ phaser.min.js:3
updateRAF @ phaser.min.js:3
window.requestAnimationFrame.forceSetTimeOut._onLoop @ phaser.min.js:3
```

Comment: I can't replicate this. How are you initially creating `general_sounds`? What happens if you don't define it to an array?

Comment: Hey James thanks for the question - I have put a bit more detail above. If I dont define the array then nothing works at all.

Comment: Which makes sense, since I believe [Interphase 1](http://phaser.io/interphase/1)'s documentation on the State manager states that all `game.load` calls should happen in `preload` to ensure they're available. Interestingly, I can't get your example to run, but I can replicate the issue if I move the load calls into `create`. The [official Play Music example](https://phaser.io/examples/v2/audio/play-music) has things broken up so that `game.load` happens in `preload` and `game.add.audio` happens in `create`. Changing your code to follow that standard works for me.

Comment: Thanks for that James very helpful - can I still call a separate function from create to do the loading? I will try what you suggest and see where this gets me.

Comment: You could absolutely break `loadGeneralSound` up, with the second adding the audio to the game.

Comment: Just did exactly that, it works :) Can you put your comments as the answer and I will accept it? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Awesome; glad it helped! And answer added. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Interphase 1](http://phaser.io/interphase/1)'s documentation on the State manager states that all `game.load` calls should happen in `preload` to ensure they're available. Interestingly, I can't get your example to run, but I can replicate the issue if I move the load calls into `create`.

The [official Play Music example](https://phaser.io/examples/v2/audio/play-music) has things broken up so that `game.load` happens in `preload` and `game.add.audio` happens in `create`. Changing your code to follow that standard works for me.

For example:

```
function preload() {
    // load general sounds into cache
    loadGeneralSound(); 
}

function create() {
    // Add audio to the array so they can be played.
    addGeneralSound();
    general_sounds[0].play();
    general_sounds[1].play();
    general_sounds[2].play();
}

// loads general sounds that are not object specific
function loadGeneralSound() {
    game.load.audio('sound.correct', 'assets/sound.general/sound.correct.mp3');
    game.load.audio('sound.incorrect', 'assets/sound.general/sound.incorrect.mp3');
    game.load.audio('voice.correct', 'assets/sound.general/sound.well_done.m4a');
}

// Add sounds to the array object so they can be referenced/played.
function addGeneralSound() {
    general_sounds[0] = game.add.audio('sound.correct');
    general_sounds[1] = game.add.audio('sound.incorrect');
    general_sounds[2] = game.add.audio('voice.correct');
}
```